# Rails - Server request blocked when using ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, actioncable

I'm having issues with ActionCable on nginx (with passenger) server. When I open a page with ActionCable the server blocks all other requests. 
I found this issue [Rails - Server Blocking on Action Cable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48432062/rails-server-blocking-on-action-cable) where the exact same problem is described, but the solution didn't help.

My nginx config

```
server {
    listen *:8020 ssl;
    server_name my-domain.com;
    root /var/www/my-domain/current/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env beta;
    passenger_app_group_name my-domain_action_cable;
    passenger_app_type rack;
    passenger_startup_file cable/config.ru;
    passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem; $
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem$
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
        # ssl on;
        listen         *:443 ssl;
        server_name my-domain.com;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_app_env beta;
        root /var/www/my-domain/current/public/;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem; $
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem$
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

/cable/config.ru:

```
require ::File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
Rails.application.eager_load!

run ActionCable.server
```

cable.yml:

```
beta:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

ActionCable config from environment file:

```
 config.action_cable.url = 'wss://my-domain.com:8020'
```

js that conects to ActionCable (using [actioncable-vue](https://github.com/mclintprojects/actioncable-vue))

```
Vue.use(ActionCableVue, {
  debug: true,
  debugLevel: 'error',
  connectionUrl: 'wss://my-domain.com:8020',
  connectImmediately: false,
}) ;
```

myChannel.rb:

```
class MyChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "my_channel_#{params[:id]}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
  end

  def broadcast_data(data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast("my_channel_#{params[:id]}", data)
  end
end
```

My guess is that the problem lies somewhere in nginx config, but I can`t figure it out.

I followed [this](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/action_cable_integration/#running-the-action-cable-server-on-a-different-host-or-port) guide for running action cable on a different server and port (I already tried running it on the same server, the problem was still there)